# HTC HERO OTA update to Android version 2.1 firmware deleted the Calibrate Touch Screen feature from the menus. How do I get it back?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, touchscreen, htc-hero

HTC directly updated over-the-air (OTA) from 1.5 android to 2.1 android firmware on my handset. Since that time, the touch-screen (which is miscalibrated) can no longer be recalibrated, because the menu item has disappeared.

I have, of course, requested support from HTC via email, but I doubt that they will find an answer here, and I suspect my phone is now junk, unless some enterprising Phone-savvy person can figure out how to restore this thing.   There is sadly no backup that I know of that I can use to restore this phone, and going back to Android 1.5 has a host of issues associated with it.

How can I get this working again?  I could use any technique that will let me recalibrate the touch screen, even if it isn't the built-in menu item, maybe there is a way to bring that up indirectly somehow, or through an add-on app?

Incidentally, [HTC HERO](http://androidforums.com/htc-hero/24348-screen-not-responsive-when-flat-surface.html)'s seem to be famous on internet cell-phone forums for glitchy capacitive touch screens.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. How long have you had your phone? If it's still under warranty/insured, you should be able to get it replaced and can make sure that the new one has a good screen. Sounds like a hardware problem to me.

Comment: You're right. I contacted HTC and they say that this kind of capacitive multi-touch screen is either auto-calibrated during a hard-reset or goes back to them for service. It was the latter.

Comment: Now I have doubts. I have already sent it to them, but in some forums, people are saying that it's a firmware glitch. So I've paid shipping so they can address this firmware glitch as a warranty repair, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this on SDX Developers forum.  You might want to try it out

===============================================================
http://forum.sdx-developers.com/android-1-5/htc-hero-virtual-keyboard-on-moment/

This is a quick guide on how to get the htc hero vk onto your moment.

(1) You will need to go onto the android market and download an app installer.  'appmanager' should work.

(2) Download the HTC virtual keyboard apk

(3) Connect phone to computer, mount the phone, then move file onto a folder on the sdcard.  unmount.

(4) open appmanager -> press 'menu' key -> select 'Install from SD'.  There you can install the .apk file. If the file is not visible, press menu again, and select 'Whole SD' so that you can see the file.

(5) Go to your home
-> go to 'Settings' -> 'Locale & text'.  Select 'Touch Input'.

(6) Go to someplace where you input text, such as messaging. Long-press on the text input field, and select 'Input Method'. Select 'Touch Input'.

If you would like to calibrate the htc vk, download this file: calibration apk

(1) follow steps 3 and 4 above.

(2) to calibrate: go to 'settings' -> 'Locale & Text' -> 'touch input' settings -> 'text input' -> select 'calibration tool'

Thanks to bjb_nyj101 for locating the htc vk; and hokansoc for locating the calibration tool.

Also note: the calibration tool isn't necessary for it to work, so you should be ok even if you can't get it to install.

=============================================================